# what's the relationship between ClassName.this and Context Class?

Tags: java, android

Im learning Android `ComponentName`, the example of the android book is:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            ComponentAttrActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

It is used to create a 2nd Activity by the 1st Activity, Im confused about the first parameter: `ComponentAttrActivity.this`. I checked on StackOverflow, most answers are about why it is `ClassName.this` not only `this`, but what I want to know is what's the relationship between the type of `Class.this` with `Context`, I am assuming the above ComponentName constructor fit the 3rd constructor below

it has 3 2-argument constructors:

```
ComponentName(String pkg, String cls)
ComponentName(Context pkg, String cls)
ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls)
```

I checked `Context` of Android API, still have no clue...

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an  abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for  application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Can anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassName.this` lets an inner class refer to the instance of its enclosing class. In your case, it is an instance of a class which is a sub-class of `Context` (for example, an `Activity` is a sub-class of `Context`, and therefore any sub-classes of `Activity` too), and therefore can be passed as the `Context` parameter.

If your constructor call to `new ComponentName(ComponentAttrActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);` is not contained in the code of an inner class, you can use `new ComponentName(this, SecondActivity.class);` instead.