# Does onCreate create an instance of the class?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. Do I understand correctly that if we write ClassName.this, do we refer to an instance of ClassName? If so, what does the QuizActivity.this parameter refer to (last line) in method of onCreate?

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;
private Question[] mQuestionBank= new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};
private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.incorrect_toast,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: java's basics: Nested classes + Anonymous classes

Comment: See this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313054/whats-the-relationship-between-classname-this-and-context-class

Comment: @Selvin I probably do not understand what is instance. I thought that instance is real "object" of some class. For example Cat cat = new Cat(); But where in my code we create this instance?

Comment: anonymous class: with `new View.OnClickListener() { someMethod() { }  }` you are creating an anonymous class inistance, inside `someMethod()` `this` reffers to this anonymous class instance ... not to outer class (QuizActivity)

Comment: @Selvin Yes, it's clear. QuizActivity.this refers to instance of QuizActivity. But where we create this instance? QuizActivity quizActivity = new...

Comment: It is created by Android OS ... you should never create Application/Service/Activity class by your own ...

Comment: @Selvin I got it. Thank you!